# how to rereive the foreign key fields in only get request using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**I have my model like this:**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=False)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')

class Resized_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='resized_images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rendition = models.ForeignKey(Rendition,related_name='rendition_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=False)
```

I am specifying imagefield of Image table as foreign key in Resized_image model,so if do a get request i should get the path present in Resized_image table also,how can i do that?

when i trigger a get request for images i am getting the output like this:

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "xyz1",
            "image": "http://10.75.12.175:7010/photos/2019/01/10/73440005-078.jpg"
}
```

but i want the Resized_image path also inside that get request

I am trying like this in serializer:

```
class resized_imagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Resized_image
         fields = ('path',)
        read_only_fields = ['path']

class imagesSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
        resized_images = resized_imagesSerializer(many=True,required=False)
        class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id','name','image','resized_images')
        read_only_fields =['resized_images']
```

if i try like this even in post request i am getting this resized_images field. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: One `Image` object can have multiple `Resized_image` since you made a one to many relationship. So which `path` do you expect to see if you fetch one `Image` object?

Comment: By the way your `imagesSerializer` looks ok to me, it should include the `resized_images` in the response, what do you see in the response? And are you sure you are fetching an image that has resized_images?

Answer (score 0):

You can access `ImageField` url by `<field_name>.url`. If `a` is instance of `Resized_image`, `a.image.url` is your image url. So you can get url in `save` method.

```
class Resized_image(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='resized_images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rendition = models.ForeignKey(Rendition,related_name='rendition_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = self.image.url
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yaa but my question is how i can get the path of Resized_image model in the Image model get request?

Comment: `Image` instance can get multiple `Resized_image`. Because it is one to many relation. I think you want one-to-one relation. Check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) @LShafiya